# android set system time error

Tags: android, time

I used

`Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 c.set(year, month - 1, day, hourOfDay, minute);
 boolean b = SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(c.getTimeInMillis());`

to set system time, it's work, but can't set exceeds the Integer.MAX_VALUE of the timeInMillis,

eg: 2016-03-09 12:34:00 (success); 2150-03-09-12:34:00 (fail).

at android source code, Settings - DateTimeSettings is used getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)).setTime, i also try to use that to set time, but has same error.

```
static void setDate(Context context, int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    long when = c.getTimeInMillis();

    if (when / 1000 < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        ((AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)).setTime(when);
    }
}
```

Logs:

`I/wpa_supplicant(461): [CTRL_IFACE]wlan0: SIGNAL_POLL
D/SystemClock(4186): Setting time of day to sec=1533218663
W/SystemClock(2005): time going backwards: prev 1884443673247396938(ioctl) vs now -526088270617409983(ioctl), tid=2005
I/PushLogSC2559(1190): [ReceiverDispatcher-91]read to Send:DA(activity/null:-1)
D/dalvikvm(1253): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 373K, 20% free 3353K/4176K, paused 20ms, total 21ms
V/AlarmClock(4152): No next alarm
V/AlarmClock(4152): AlarmInitReceiver finished`

who can help me, thanks!

Comment: why are you checking (when / 1000 < Integer.MAX_VALUE)  ?

Comment: @ZumryMohamed ,I don't checking Integer.MAX_VALUE, it's android source code.

Comment: can you send your error log ?

Comment: @ZumryMohamed sorry, i forgot it, logs is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google's report is "whether or not this works will depend on your specific hardware. real-time clock (RTC) chips have lower and upper bounds on the date range they support, and crappy ones often don't bother with more than 100 years (because they assume you're only ever going to set the clock to the actual time, and that the device won't be used before it was manufactured or after it's long obsolete). but that's mainly a problem for future museum curators."

You can see [android issues #198150](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198150)